# Where is Appropriate to Put AWS Keys

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm learning about Strongloop, it's pretty good so far.

Question:  What is the appropriate place to put AWS keys?  config.json?  ..and how would I access them from my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would not put those credentials in any file that is committed. I usually find environment variables to be the best balance of convenience and security.

If you are using strong-pm, then you would do this with `slc ctl env-set`. If you are using some other supervisor, then you'll need to consult its docs.

A lot of times it is enough to use Upstart or systemd directly, which both make it fairly easy to set environment variables in the service process.

Answer (score 0):

Other than above answer, what you can do is put these in your release procedure.

What we have done in our product is all these entries are kept in a config file which is deployed from the shared folder.
Let me elaborate it.

we have local config files in the git. and separate config files on production servers in a folder names as shared, now, when ever a tag release is deployed from git, the shared folder overwrite these config files.